# Making calculations in inheritance classe

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to make the program so that the `dicountPrice` would be equal to the corresponding if statement. I'm not too sure if it
s my if statement or if I'm missing something in my class. I've tried doing super.purchases and this.purchases and as of now I'm stumped.

Sample output:

> Name: Snow White
>   
> Address: 111 Dwarf Lane
>   
> Telephone: 555-0000
>   
> Customer Number: 200-A010
>   
> Customer Type: Preferred
>   
> Total Purchases: 2566.0
>   
> Total Owed: 2566.0
>   
> Total Discount Percent: 0.0
>   
> Total Owed Minus Discount: 2566.0

But I need the discount percent to be 10

TIA

```
public class Customer extends Person {
protected String customerNumber, customerType;
protected double purchases;

Customer(){

    super(DEFAULT_VALUE,DEFAULT_VALUE,DEFAULT_VALUE);
    setCustomerType(DEFAULT_VALUE);
    setPurchases(0.0);

}

Customer(String name, String address, String phone, String cusNum, String cusType, double purch){
    super (name,address, phone);
    customerNumber = cusNum;
    customerType = cusType;
    purchases = purch;
}
public void setCustomerNumber(String custNum){
    customerNumber = custNum;
}
public String getCustomerNumber(){
    return customerNumber;
}
public void setCustomerType(String cusType){
    customerType = cusType;
}
public String getCustomerType(){
    return customerType;
}
public void setPurchases(double purch){
    purchases = purch;
}
public double getPurchases(){
    return purchases;
}
public double getTotalOwed(){
    return purchases;
}
public String toString(){ 
      return super.toString() + "\nCustomer Number: " + customerNumber + "\nCustomer Type: " + customerType + 
              "\nTotal Purchases: " + purchases + "\nTotal Owed: " + purchases;
}
}



public class PreferredCustomer extends Customer {
    private double discountPercent=0.0;

    PreferredCustomer(){
        super(DEFAULT_VALUE,DEFAULT_VALUE,DEFAULT_VALUE,DEFAULT_VALUE, DEFAULT_VALUE,0.0);
    }
    PreferredCustomer(String name, String address, String phone, String customerNumber, String customerType, double purchases){
        super (name, address, phone, customerNumber, customerType, purchases);
    }
    public void setDiscountPercent(double dp){
        discountPercent = dp;

    }
    public double getDiscountPercent(){
        if (purchases >= 2000){
            discountPercent = 100 * .10;

        }
        else if (purchases >= 1500 && purchases <2000){
            discountPercent = 100 * .7;
        }
        else if (purchases >= 1000 && purchases <1500){
            discountPercent = 100 * .6;
        }
        else if (purchases >=500 && purchases <1000){
            discountPercent= 100 * .5;
        }
        else if(purchases<500){
            discountPercent = 0;
        }

        return discountPercent ;
    }
    public double getTotalOwed(){
        return purchases - discountPercent;
    }
    public String toString(){ 
      return super.toString() + "\nTotal Discount Percent: " + discountPercent + "\nTotal Owed Minus Discount: " + this.getTotalOwed();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I see I didn't specify it but my discountPercent is returning as 0.0

Comment: Can you provide 'Customer' Class source and how you instantiate and print your 'PreferredCustomer' object?

Comment: PreferredCustomer b2 = new PreferredCustomer("Snow White", "111 Dwarf Lane","555-0000","200-A010","Preferred", 2566.00);                               System.out.println(b2);

Comment: You have to actually call getDiscountPercent(). Otherwise your calculation is not triggered

Comment: Wow thank you so much. It's the simplest things that can mess your program up @Benedikt

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your source, the issue comes from `getDiscountPercent`; You do calculations and modify members in a getter function which is a bad idea. A getter should only return data and not modify the internal state of the class.

A solution would be to create a private method called `calculateDiscountPercent` and call it internally whenever you modify members that would affect the discount percent value. Like this:

```
private void calculateDiscountPercent(){
    if (purchases >= 2000){
        discountPercent = 100 * .10;

    }
    else if (purchases >= 1500 && purchases <2000){
        discountPercent = 100 * .7;
    }
    else if (purchases >= 1000 && purchases <1500){
        discountPercent = 100 * .6;
    }
    else if (purchases >=500 && purchases <1000){
        discountPercent= 100 * .5;
    }
    else if(purchases<500){
        discountPercent = 0;
    }
}
```

From the source, I see that the `discountPercent` is affected by the `purchases` member from its super class. Therefore, override its setter function to calculate the discount every time the purchase changes. Like so:

```
@Override
public void setPurchases(double purch){
    super.setPurchases(purch);
    this.calculateDiscountPercent();
}
```

Complete class would look like:

```
public class PreferredCustomer extends Customer {
    private double discountPercent=0.0;

    PreferredCustomer(){
        super(DEFAULT_VALUE,DEFAULT_VALUE,DEFAULT_VALUE,DEFAULT_VALUE, DEFAULT_VALUE,0.0);
        this.calculateDiscountPercent();
    }
    PreferredCustomer(String name, String address, String phone, String customerNumber, String customerType, double purchases){
        super (name, address, phone, customerNumber, customerType, purchases);
        this.calculateDiscountPercent();
    }
    public void setDiscountPercent(double dp){
        discountPercent = dp;
    }
    public double getDiscountPercent(){
        return discountPercent ;
    }
    @Override
    public void setPurchases(double purch){
        super.setPurchases(purch);
        this.calculateDiscountPercent();
    }
    private void calculateDiscountPercent(){
        if (purchases >= 2000){
            discountPercent = 100 * .10;

        }
        else if (purchases >= 1500 && purchases <2000){
            discountPercent = 100 * .7;
        }
        else if (purchases >= 1000 && purchases <1500){
            discountPercent = 100 * .6;
        }
        else if (purchases >=500 && purchases <1000){
            discountPercent= 100 * .5;
        }
        else if(purchases<500){
            discountPercent = 0;
        }
    }
    public double getTotalOwed(){
        return purchases - discountPercent;
    }
    public String toString(){ 
      return super.toString() + "\nTotal Discount Percent: " + discountPercent + "\nTotal Owed Minus Discount: " + this.getTotalOwed();
    }
}
```